# Populating tree view in vb.net from Postgres Database

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

The vb.net code for populating tree view from the SQL Server Database is given in following link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320755

I tried the code given in the above link to solve my problem but I was unable to change the code of SQL Sever for Postgres Database.

I want to do the same thing using vb.net and database Postgres.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate tree view for parent child relation in same table in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848603/how-to-populate-tree-view-for-parent-child-relation-in-same-table-in-vb-net)

Comment: @Milen A. Radev: This question is for if the relation is in different table. My next question is for the parent child relation in same table.

Answer (score 1):

You failed to tell us what exactly is not working for your, but my guess is the non-standard SQL that is used in that example.

Remove the "bracket quoting" from the SQL Statements, and it should run fine on PostgreSQL

`Select * from [Order Details]` is invalid SQL for PostgreSQL (and every other DBMS except SQL Server)

Change the table's name to e.g. `order_details` and then you can run `SELECT * FROM order_details` leaving out the square brackets

And of course, the connection string needs to be changed as well (but I cannot help you there as I don't know VisualBasic)

Comment: For SQL Server 2008, we have to do 
**Dim DACustomers As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Country FROM customers WHERE country = 'Germany'", CNnwind)** but what we have to do for Postgre SQL? And also I am unable to populate the data in tree view if the parent-child relation is in same table.

Comment: I can only answer for the **SQL** Part in there - which seems fine for PostgreSQL. I have no idea about the VisualBasic part.