# How to populate tree view for parent child relation in same table

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, treeview

The database structure is:

```
Id    Name     ParentId 
1     File     NULL
2     Open     1
3     Save     1
4     Exit     1
5     Edit     NULL
6     Cut      5
7     Copy     5
```

I want to display the above data in tree view using VB.Net like:

```
File
----- Open
----- Save
----- Exit
Edit
----- Cut
----- Copy
```

I am using the database **PostgreSQL**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub AddTreeItems(id as Integer, node as TreeNode)
    dim s = id.ToString
    If id = 0 Then
        s = "NULL"
    End If
    r as new Query("select * from table where parent =" & s)
    While r.read()
        dim n as new TreeNode(r["name"])
        node.Add(n)
        AddTreeItems(r["id"],n)
    End While
End Sub
```

The query function is kinda pseudo-code, but I think you get the picture.